# О книге "Неучебник по русскому языку"

Tags: общие-вопросы

Книга рекламируется на Грамоте.ру

**"Неучебник по русскому языку" – в шорт-листе конкурса "Книга года"**

Определился шорт-лист в номинации «Учебник XXI века» конкурса «Книга года» – 2018. **В шорт-листе – «Неучебник по русскому языку»,** вышедший летом в издательстве Clever. Авторы «Неучебника» – профессор-исследователь НИУ ВШЭ д. ф. н., **проф. М. А. Кронгауз**, старший научный сотрудник Института русского языка им. В. В. Виноградова РАН, **заместитель главного редактора портала «Грамота.ру»** к. ф. н. Е. В. Арутюнова и учитель школы «Интеллектуал» Б. А. Панов, разрабатывающий **новые типы упражнений по русскому языку**. Двое авторов – М. А. Кронгауз и Е. В. Арутюнова – **члены Орфографической комиссии РАН.**

**Вопросы:**

1) **Насколько удачно название книги?** Слово ***неучебник*** при слитном написании НЕ имеет утвердительное значение, а какое именно?

2) Как вы относитесь к тому, что авторами **нестандартного учебника** являются **ведущие специалисты** в области правописания?

3) Если вы читали книги **М. А. Кронгауза,** то какое у вас сложилось мнение о них? https://www.livelib.ru/author/300605/top-maksim-krongauz

Я однажды в магазине полистала "Русский язык на грани нервного срыва", но как-то не очень заинтересовалась. Может быть, напрасно?

Comment: Призываю всех участников проявлять уважение к авторам, несмотря ни на какие обстоятельства. Вообще говоря, обсуждать людей, особенно на сайте, не очень хорошо, поэтому давайте сконцентрируемся именно на их работе. Jasmin, ваш вопрос интересен и связан с языкознанием, несмотря на то, что мнение играет в нем значительную роль. Предлагаю __сделать исключение__ и поговорить об этих книгах.

Comment: А что не так с названием книги? Учебник по любому предмету - а тем более по русскому языку - у школьников, как правило, вызывает жуткую скуку, если не отвращение, поэтому и "неучебник".

Comment: https://youtu.be/Qk4H-fPl4v8, думаю, ответы вы найдете здесь.

Answer (score 2):

У меня есть ответ только на первую пару вопросов.

1-а. Название противоречиво и ассоциируется у меня с наскучившей словотворческой находчивостью рекламщиков (не исключаю, что издатели его предложили). Трудно абстрагироваться от факта входимости в название сочетания "неуч" (то ли учить их задумано, то ли плодить). Не хочется обидеть авторов — надеюсь, они этих строк не читают.

1-б. Понятно, что авторы хотели выразить на самом деле: не учить, а занять, заинтересовать и направить.

Comment: Да, можно было бы назвать книгу, например, так: Занимательная орфография", но  это название не так занимательно для публики. Мне приходилось читать книги подобного жанра, но сама идея развлечения при обучении  мне не кажется верной, а "неучебники" выглядели довольно убого. Увлечь школьников, как мне кажется,   можно еще не решенными проблемами, показав им  историю орфографии, обозначив логику решения орфографических задач. Кстати, авторы наконец объяснят нам проблему с птичкой зарянкой, которую наконец-то  отважились написать через букву А.

Comment: Мнения о двух первых книгах (орфография 5-6 классов по 500 руб за томик) противоречивая. (1)Чудесный, полезный «Неучебник»! Мы приобрели сразу две части... И самое главное – все объясняется на примере веселого стишка или рассказа. (2) Я преподаватель русского языка. Пролистала эту книгу в книжном магазине с чувством "как хорошо, что деньги целы, не надо тратиться на эту туфту".

Comment: Название отсылает к Пелевину, был у него такой персонаж, рекламный креативщик. "Не-кола для Николы".

Answer (score 2):

> 1) Насколько удачно название книги? Слово неучебник при слитном
>   написании НЕ имеет утвердительное значение, а какое именно?

//--

> Почему у книг такое необычное название – «Неучебник по русскому
>   языку»? Потому что это и учебник, и не учебник одновременно.

http://gramota.ru/lenta/news/8_3331

> 2) Как вы относитесь к тому, что авторами нестандартного учебника
>   являются ведущие специалисты в области правописания?

Ничего не имею против того, что специалисты исповедуют нестандартные методы, но, чтобы иметь мнение, всегда смотрю содержание учебника, а не авторов. Данный "неучебник" не видел, потому воздержусь от оценки. 
Но в "закрытом виде" сильно напоминает... как бы это сказать... пропагандистскую кампанию.

> 3) Если вы читали книги М. А. Кронгауза, то какое у вас сложилось
>   мнение о них?

Настороженное. Хотя последнее время не считаю нужным следить за его публикациями.